# Duplicate results from MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
  <?php

$select =  mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT field_2 FROM info4");  
 if (! $select) {
die('Query unfunctional ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
   ?>

<table>
<td><select name="City">

<?php
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
foreach($res as $value){
echo "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
}}
?>
</select></td></table>
```

where `$con` is the connection.

But this outputs the dropdown with all of the values duplicated. For example if I had 1 and 2 in my table, it outputs: 1/1/2/2 (in the dropdown). I'm supposing I'm making a mistake in my code--can anyone see it by any chance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look into using pdo sir out Mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. foreach loop in this case is unneccessary.

```
<?php
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
echo "<option>" . $res["field_2"] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! Just for future reference: in what case should I use the foreach loop?

Comment: You would never have to use foreach inside while loop when fetching data from result set. Every iteration of while loop pulls a row from the table. Then if you want a column from a row then you just get it by $res["col1"], $res["col2"] and so on.

Answer (score 3):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) defaults to the result return type `MYSQLI_BOTH`, which returns both associative and non-associative values.  Why this is, I don't know, but the array it returns is:

```
$res = array(0 => '1', 'field_2' => '1');
```

You can solve this by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or specifying `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as the return value.  My preferred fix would be:

```
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    echo "<option>$res[field_2]</option>";
}
```